# How to get a property from a trait implementation in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

I have a trait, called `MyTrait`.

```
package properties

trait MyTrait {
    abstract String property

    String getThatProperty() {
        "$property is that property"
    }
}
```

Then I have a class implementing the trait.

```
package properties

class PropertiesTesting implements MyTrait {
    String property = 'Hello'
}
```

The problem is, when I go and call `PropertiesTesting#getThatProperty()`, it returns `"null is that property"`. How can I fix that so it returns `"x is that property"` with `x` varying depending on the implementation? I do not want to rewrite code for each class that implements the trait.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would disagree that encapsulating state in a trait is a good choice. Even though it might seen like something that is possible to do, it carries the same problems as extending classes with their state.

Solution to your problem is even simpler - let your trait defines `abstract String getProperty()` method instead. Something like this:

```
trait MyTrait {
  abstract String getProperty()

  String getThatProperty() {
    "$property is that property"
  }
}

class PropertiesTesting implements MyTrait {
  String property = 'Hello'
}

def properties = new PropertiesTesting()

assert properties.getThatProperty() == 'Hello is that property'
```

Adding a field `property` in `PropertiesTesting` adds a proper `getProperty()` method and when you call `getThatProperty()` method for the trait is uses `getProperty()` from `PropertiesTesting` class. It's easier and more straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to simply use `object.properties`.

To get the property `property` of `PropertiesTesting`, I can use `instance.properties['property']`.

Comment: should be this.properties['property']

Answer (score 0):

It takes the trait's property (which is null) instead of the class's property.
Comment out the trait's String property and add a println command if you want to print the sentence.

```
package properties

trait MyTrait {
    //abstract String property

    String getThatProperty() {
        println "$property is that property"
    }
}
class PropertiesTesting implements MyTrait {
    String property = 'Hello'
}
def instance = new PropertiesTesting()
instance.getThatProperty()
```